# Can't use list box DataTemplate: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a very simple XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MonteChat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="364" 
        Width="320" Height="480"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="/MonteChat;component/Resources/Images/person.png" />
        <Label Content="{Binding User.Name}" Height="33" Margin="82,12,12,0" Name="labelUserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" ClipToBounds="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
        <ListBox Margin="12,82,12,12" Name="listContacts" ItemsSource="{Binding User.Contacts}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using MonteChat.Model;

namespace MonteChat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            var user = new ChatUser();
            user.Name = "Felipe Machado";
            user.AddContact(new ChatUser {
                Name = "Luciana Vicente",
            });
            User = user;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ChatUser User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The ChatUser class is straight-forward (I'm not using a ViewModel, and it doesn't have propety changed notification. I'm only writing this for a prototype. I'll use MVVM in the final application).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MonteChat.Model
{
    public class ChatUser 
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set;  }
        public virtual string Alias { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            return Id.Equals(obj);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
        public IEnumerable<ChatUser> Contacts {
            get { return contacts; }
        }
        public HashSet<ChatUser> contacts = new HashSet<ChatUser>();
        public bool HasContact(ChatUser contact) {
            return contacts.Contains(contact);
        }
        public void AddContact(ChatUser contact) {
            if (!HasContact(contact))
                contacts.Add(contact);
        }
        public void DeleteContact(ChatUser contact) {
            if (HasContact(contact))
                contacts.Remove(contact);
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the application I get this error:

```
{"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}
```

If I remove the DataItemTemplate from the list box it works:

```
<Window x:Class="MonteChat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="364" 
        Width="320" Height="480"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="/MonteChat;component/Resources/Images/person.png" />
        <Label Content="{Binding User.Name}" Height="33" Margin="82,12,12,0" Name="labelUserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" ClipToBounds="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
        <ListBox Margin="12,82,12,12" Name="listContacts" ItemsSource="{Binding User.Contacts}">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...but I want to style the list box to show the user picture, add some action buttons, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `ListBox.ItemTemplate` tag

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
```

Without that WPF assumes you want to define items and you already bind `ItemsSource` hence the error you're getting

Comment: That's what happens when you start prototyping in WPF with no experience on it whatsoever... You ask yourself: "That's the right tool for the job... It shouldn't be too difficult to learn it in one day :-)" Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. XAML is actually very simple to understand. If you cannot specify something inline as an attribute, like `<MyTag MyProperty=...`, then you need to do it inside `MyTag` but then in the name of the property you need to include name of the patent tag. `<MyTag><MyTag.MyProperty>` otherwise you define value for default content property as specified in `[ContentPropertyAttribute("Items")]` attribute and for each [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), as you can see on MSDN, it's `Items` property